error CORS Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not equal to the supplied origin
I'm trying to load a page from an external domain but I have a CORS problem:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.first.com/test/test'
(redirected from 'https://second.com/xyzwy') from origin
'https://www.first.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://second.com'
that is not equal to the supplied origin.

On second.com I added to .htaccess:
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://www.first.com"
    </IfModule> 

On first.com I added to .htaccess:
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://second.com"
</IfModule>

If on first.com I modify the value on .htaccess with Access-Control-Allow-Origin * it will work, but for safety reasons I don't want it.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>


The origin of your request is https://www.first.com, so that is what you would need to add "on first.com" as well here.

If you're doing an XHR request from the browser then the "origin" of the calling page doesn't change, just because you did a redirect on the server-side. The error message clearly states that https://www.first.com is the origin the request is coming from - so obviously that isn't the same as https://www.second.com in your first.com .htaccess file.

I guess that all you need to do is change the .htaccess in first.com to Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://first.com" - although then it shouldn't even constitute a CORS request in the first place (except perhaps due to the redirect - I'm a bit hazy on that point TBH without going and looking up in documentation)

Hello, i try to add to htaccess in first origin domain  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://first.com" or Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://www.first.com", and show me same: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://www.first.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin. i don't understand
